# Live link .CSV in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins, link

I have a .CSV that is updated each time I make any changes to my input sheet in .XLSM.

When I add/display the .CSV by "Add Delimited Text Layer" I cannot then update the .CSV as QGIS is then using it.

Is it possible to have a link between the .CSV and QGIS that still allows me to edit the .CSV then changes automatically refresh in QGIS.

Do I need to do via a Join instead of delimited layer ?

Answer (score 3):

Could you consider trying out the [Spreadsheet Layers plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SpreadsheetLayers/) and see if it plays ball with a de-formatted version of your XLSM? (So instead of having it save to a CSV try a simple XLSX file)

I have previously used this with XLSX files where I need to edit data in Excel live while having QGIS open (and seeing the updates live). See below for an example.

[image]

However... in my experience, it very quickly gets wonky with headers - it thinks the data are headers, or shifts them seemingly randomly to the right, etc. If your macro rewrites the entire file then I am not sure how well it will work with this.

It is the best solution I can think of without resorting to a database - which is much more robust, but I appreciate wanting a solution that allows direct editing in the Excel GUI (for the latter, you may have to look into postgres/sqlite extensions for Excel such as Devart)

Comment: I am still getting the issue with not being able to save the file when having QGIS open. Are there any specific settings you used when adding the spreadsheet layer ?

Comment: No, I simply told it where the X and Y columns were. However, I directly edited the XLSX loaded using Spreadsheet Layer in Excel itself. It may be that the mechanism your macro uses to update the spreadsheet doesn't work with QGIS's handling of the file.

Comment: Got it working.... but i see what you mean by the shifting of data .... any fixes you have found ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I got so fed up that I stopped using Excel for data manipulation and just did everything in Qgis or in a database

Answer (score 0):

So the *.csv is updated by the *.xlsm file by some macro or automation there? It writes a new date on the attribute of the *.csv file but keeps the name the same?

When you add a layer of *.csv data as a delimited text layer, you should get an option in the there for `watch file`. My understanding this will check the date of the *.csv file at least each time you open the project, if not more frequently (perhaps there is a right click refresh option on the layer?).

With regard the join, presumably there is some location data somewhere. If it is already in the *.csv file, in theory you should be able make a map from that. If the data already sits in the project as another layer, yes you should join it with common key column.

---

**EDIT**

After considering comments / updates to question - no, it is not possible to have dynamic input to QGIS via a csv file.

Minimum viable alternative in my opinion would be to install postgresql (and postgis) on local machine and write changes to that db either via DBeaver or LibreOfficeBase.

Comment: Yes that is correct the file name stays the same but the data is updated.


The issue i have is that i want to have the project open all the time. Whilst the project is open the .CSV cannot be edited as QGIS is "using" it.


The macro cannot then append the .CSV as it is in theory "read only"


The data refers to a location for each set yes. So if i make a shape file from the delimited text layer can I then join back to the .CSV?

Comment: I think OP means that once QGIS is opened the CSV is locked for editing (whether manually or via the xlsm). The question is probably more about whether it's possible to have CSVs loaded in QGIS without being locked for editing. edit: didn't see OP's reply above.

Comment: @she_weeds that would obviously be the easiest solution yes but i don't know if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible... Sometimes.

I have a similar task whereby I want to display the data in QGIS but want to be able to live update it in Excel.  Unfortunately I still haven't figured out exactly what the circumstances are for this to work, but I can confirm that on a task that I do a lot of times on some projects, both QGIS and Excel let me edit and save the CSV in Excel and it immediately updates in QGIS.  The problem is that even though it's the same file types when I do this task, sometimes it lets me do it, sometimes it doesn't (the file is locked) which is very frustrating.  The last time I needed to do this task was in January 2021 so I must have been using QGIS 3.10.

The process that I had which made it work more often than not is:

1. open the CSV in Excel;
2. add delimited text layer in QGIS with "Watch file" ticked;
3. I can set styling for the layer in QGIS - this is how I know that it works in both Excel and QGIS i.e. Excel lets me save and on saving, certain data points change colour as a result of the new data;
4. after all updates done in QGIS, then save the project.

Note: sometimes the layer would disappear from the display (but not from the layers panel) in QGIS. If this happened, I would just need to click on the refresh button (or F5) in QGIS.