# Live synchronisation Excel to QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, excel

I am looking for a solution to synchronize a vector layer to an Excel-file in both directions. So if I add a geometry within the vector layer, it shall also be written in the Excel-file and if I change any information in the Excel-file, it shall be written in the vector layer.

I've tried the "join"-function within the properties of the layer and the "relationship"-function within the properties of the project.

Comment: What kind of vector layer? Is the data hosted somewhere? If so, and the server that is hosting your data has some interface like WFS you can use PowerQuery to get the data to Excel. In the other direction you would need some custom VBA where you could use WFS-T for CRUD operations.

Comment: There is an ExcelSync plugin which you might look at.   I have not used so I can't say if it would do what you need or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was the [Spreadsheet Layers plugin which I tried](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/359606/98784) but then stopped using a couple of years ago because unless the Excel spreadsheet had zero or close to zero formatting it would start doing strange things with the headers. It may have improved since then so worth trying.

The most robust solution I could work out at the time was using a sqlite based spatial data source and using [Devart plugin for Excel](https://www.devart.com/excel-addins/sqlite/) to update data (and it supports proper CRUD that would otherwise be made a mess of in Excel). It does require extra steps to allow editing and proper syncing/saving of data which is good for data integrity but obviously requires pointing out and getting used to for people who are only used to using Excel.

However, the Devart plugin is paid (after a free 30 day trial). They also have one for Postgres.

Also, when loading the data source you have to hide all geometry fields I think as it doesn't recognise the datatype.

Comment: Thanks, the Spreadsheet plugin works for me. I had to create a spreadsheet layer and copy all my data to this layer. Now its synchronizing every changes I do in Excel or the Vector layer. For the actual purpose it works out.

Comment: @lesto if the solution worked for you, you should accept the answer: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235